# 502 Bad Gateway on Elastic Load Balancer

Tags: https, amazon-elb, http-status-codes, mulesoft

I have a load balancer which redirects to an ec2 server which has a mulesoft application running on a port,
Load balancer redirects whatever comes through to that port

I get a 502 bad gateway everytime I try to POST data through postman, as soon as I post again the request goes through. 
1st Attempt: Fail with 502 bad gateway
2nd Attempt (Immediate): Goes through

I increased the timeout on the load balancer to 5 minutes but still I get 502 bad gateway on the first try

Any help/suggestions appreciated

Comment: 502 is not related to a timeout. It is related to not connecting or some other issue. There are several causes for it. You should provide more details of the request. For example enable HTTP Wire logging on Mule and see if it reaches it.

Comment: The request comes from an external service in the form of webhooks, all they do is POST to our DNS, which redirects to the Amazon Load Balancer which verifies the source of the webhook and forwards to the mulesoft application over https, I will try the wire logging and see how it goes

Comment: When I point to the Mulesoft listener directly, everything flows through but as soon as I point to Load balancer, same stuff happens

Comment: The problem seems to be with the load balancer. Without more details of the configurations and traffic it is difficult that someone can help.